# Easy way to do CSS3 animation?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm not familiar with CSS3 animation, but i do want to add some CSS3 animation to my web elements,  could you please show me some way to do css3 animation in a quick way? for example, do we have some jquery plugin to do css3 animation? thanks!

Comment: http://www.css3maker.com/css3-animation.html

Comment: Learn how to do it once and you won't forget it. It's pretty simple.

Comment: _"I'm not familiar with CSS3 animation"_ - There are a few tutorials around that I'm sure you could find with Google. Regarding jQuery plugins for this, isn't the point of CSS3 animation that it can (ideally) be done all in CSS, no JS (except maybe to add or remove classes dynamically)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Acutally i know some very good CSS3 animation file which name is [animate.CSS](http://daneden.me/animate/), it can quickly help you to add css animation to your element. you can use jquery addClass method to add anmition on the fly as below:

$('#somediv').addClass('animate fadeInRightBig');

then youo can make the div anmiated with fadeIn effect. it supports up to 60 different effect, i'm sure you can find the ones you need. you may check ou this little [game demo](http://www.gbin1.com/technology/democenter/20120812-animate-css/index.html) which is developed by animate.css.  Hope you will like it!

Answer (score 2):

No need to use `jquery plugin`, just refer [CSS3.com cheat sheet page](http://www.css3.com/cheat-sheets/)

It populates all the properties of CSS3 and also compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

There are many tools online which generate snippets of CSS that contain animation information.  Once you have generated the result you want, try it by pasting it into your CSS file inside any valid CSS selector.

One of the benefits of CSS animations is that they don't rely on JavaScript, so a jQuery plugin probably isn't a good match.

"css3 animation generator" is a good google search phrase. I looked at the top results and several of them were useful, such as:

- http://www.css3maker.com/index.html
- http://matthewlein.com/ceaser/

Answer (score 0):

Try this one http://cssanimate.com/, this tool is for generating css3 keyframes animation